# UISearchBar out of screen bounds when navigation bar translucent = false

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8

I try add UISearchBarController to tableView, but when i set UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false then UISearchBar hide out of screen

in TableViewController

```
var resultSearchC: UISearchController = UISearchController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.resultSearchC = ({
        let c = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        c.searchResultsUpdater = self

        c.searchBar.translucent = true

        c.searchBar.barTintColor =  .redColor()
        c.searchBar.sizeToFit()

        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = c.searchBar

        return c
    })()

    // self.edgesForExtendedLayout = .None

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

AppDelegate:

```
let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBar.appearance()

    navBarAppearance.barStyle = .Black
    navBarAppearance.translucent = false
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to set extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars to true in viewDidLoad().

```
extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true;
```

Comment: You have to write it in your UINavigationController subclass, not in your active view controller

Comment: @ArtyomDevyatov @Andrespch For iOS10 and iOS11, no need to subclass UINavigationController, you can just do:

`let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootVC)
 navVC.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true`