# iOS 9 searchBar disappears from table header view when UISearchController is active

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, ios9, uisearchcontroller

The structure:

View1 (click a button) -> present modally (MyModalView: UITableViewController)

MyModalView has UISearchController embedded. The searchBar of UISearchController is placed in MyModalView.tableView.tableHeaderView.

It's been working fine since iOS 8.0. However on iOS 9, the searchBar disappear when the UISearchController is active. Please take a look at theses pictures below

The modal view:[image: modal view]

UISearchController active on iOS 8:[image: search bar in iOS 8]

UISearchController active on iOS 9:[image: search bar in iOS 9]

The very standard code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Dynamically create a search controller using anonymous function
    self.resultSearchController = ({
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        controller.searchBar.delegate = self

        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar

        return controller
    })()

    // Auto sizing row & cell height
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 130
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.definesPresentationContext = true

    // No footer for better presentation
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView.init(frame: CGRectZero)
}
```

This issue also happens in iOS 9.1 beta...

Any idea / pointer would be deeply appreciated

Cheers.

Comment: For me, this only happens on the device (not in Simulator).

Comment: Hi @IanDundas I posted my answer below would you want to try it to see if it'll fix your problem?

Comment: yes, actually @Shwethascar's fixes it lucky - thanks though. Just adding some context for others, that it only happens for me on the actual device.

Comment: Try searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false

Answer (score 66, accepted):

It seems all of us got the same problem but they were solved in different ways. However none of the suggested answers worked for me :(. Nevertheless thank you all for your time.

I got a solution that solved my problem. It is setting Extend Edges - Under Opaque Bars of my (MyModalView: UITableViewController) to true in the Storyboard using Interface Builder.

In summary:

MyModalView: UITableViewController, in Storyboard using Interface Builder has

Extend Edges:
- Under Top Bars ticked
- Under Bottom Bars ticked
- Under Opaque Bars ticked

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Yep. Extend Edges: - Under Opaque Bars ticked in Storyboard did the trick.

Comment: This  has been plaguing me for hours. Thank you so much.

Comment: Which properties do these checkboxes correspond to? Many people don't use Interface Builder.

Answer (score 70):

I'm not sure what exactly is the problem but I 'fixed' it by:

```
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
self.definesPresentationContext = NO;
```

My guess is that `UISearchController` is doing something funky when it is trying to present as a navigation bar. So, this is a hack but it at least doesn't block the user. The search bar doesn't do the cool animation and cover up the navigation bar.

Comment: Only needed the first line `searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false` (swift)

Comment: Yes, Only need searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false, That's real solution.

Comment: NO,not a real solution .Wht if we need to hide navigation bar and SearchBar is hidden under statusbar..?

Comment: I needed both these

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This is the only thing that worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: This is *still* the only answer I've found that fixes my problem. Agreed with above comments that the first part was sufficient.

Answer (score 36):

I found it's the simulated metrics (top bar) in storyboard that's cause this problem.
In my case, the following lines work, but I still don't know why.

```
- (void)willPresentSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
    // do something before the search controller is presented
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
}

-(void)willDismissSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
}
```

Comment: it happens even with pure code . I bet that translucent = false actually removes  a view or something instead of disabling the translucent effect hence the search bar simply goes beyond the visible area

Comment: don't forget to set the searchController delegate to the class implementing these methods (usually self)

Comment: This was the solution that made it work for me! Thanks!

Comment: `searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .default` in `willPresent` and `.minimal` in `willDismiss` helped for me.

Comment: Solved our issue as well - in our case the navigationBar overlaps the searchBar  - setting translucent to on / off during inside the delegates fixed the issue.

Answer (score 19):

I had to

```
self.aNavigationController?.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
```

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29453228/uisearchbar-out-of-screen-bounds-when-navigation-bar-translucent-false) but in my case it was not on the viewDidLoad method. I had to try different views until it worked. Now I can have both a custom navigation bar color and the search bar,

Comment: Great Answer Jigzat !

Comment: This should be added along with @David Trang answer.

Answer (score 10):

Thanks @wiles duan and @Techprimate

In my case, I fixed this issue by setting:

```
self.definesPresentationContext = NO;
```

And implement the following 2 methods in UISearchControllerDelegate

```
- (void)willPresentSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
    // do something before the search controller is presented
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
}

-(void)willDismissSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
}
```

Comment: I fixed mine by just implementing the delegate methods

Answer (score 6):

I fixed it in my case by removing

`definesPresentationContext = true`

I didn't test yet if there are any disadvantages of removing this!

Comment: Adding this fixed it for me. 

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and when I debugged the UI on Xcode I found that the `UISearchBar` view was moved to another view and the width was zeroed.

I fixed it by setting `definesPresentationContext` property of the `UISearchController` to `false`, and setting it `true` for the containing `UITableViewController`.

I added only one line to your `viewDidLoad()`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Dynamically create a search controller using anonymous function
    self.resultSearchController = ({
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controller.definesPresentationContext = false    // Disable the presentation controller

        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        controller.searchBar.delegate = self

        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar

        return controller
    })()

    // Auto sizing row & cell height
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 130
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.definesPresentationContext = true    // This one remains the same

    // No footer for better presentation
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView.init(frame: CGRectZero)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a navigation bar in this place of an app. None of other SO posts helped me, so I've fixed it this way:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [[[self searchController] searchBar] sizeToFit];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the navigationBar permanently to translucent in storyboard solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

It works

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = !self.navigationController!.navigationBar.translucent
}
```

Comment: I had to do this in viewDidAppear otherwise it breaks again somehow. Thanks @Apple.

Comment: This fixed it for me as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide you navigation bar, and present search controller full screen, set the following on your navigation bar and search bar won't dissapper:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sc.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
```

does the trick for me

```
lazy var searchController:UISearchController = {
        let sc = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        sc.searchResultsUpdater = self
        sc.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        sc.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
        sc.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        return sc
    }()
```

Answer (score 0):

None of them worked for me, I fixed it using this hack

```
func position(for bar: UIBarPositioning) -> UIBarPosition {
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
        return .top
    } else {
        if iOSVersion <= 9 {
            return .top
        }
        return .topAttached
    }


}
```