# Search Controller with multiple section in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uisearchcontroller

I have a UIViewController in which I have a UITableView and inside that tableview I have multiple sections which have some item and I have to search with itemname inside that tableview. I have declared this in my view controller

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    definesPresentationContext = true
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 39.0/255.0, green: 203.0/255.0, blue: 192.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search item"

    var sections = [Category A, Category B, Category C]
    var itemsA = [["Item": "item A","ItemId" : "1"],["Item": "itemB","ItemId" : "2"],["Item": "item C","ItemId" : "3"]]
    var itemsB = [["Item": "item A","ItemId" : "1"],["Item": "itemB","ItemId" : "2"],["Item": "item C","ItemId" : "3"]]
    var itemsC = [["Item": "item A","ItemId" : "1"],["Item": "itemB","ItemId" : "2"],["Item": "item C","ItemId" : "3"]]
 }

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if searchController.isActive {
        return 1
    }
    return self.sections.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if searchController.isActive {
        return filteredShops.count
    }
switch (section) {
    case 0: 
       return itemsA.count
    case 1: 
       return itemsB.count
    default: 
       return itemsC.count
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "StoreCell") as! UITableViewCell

    if searchController.isActive {
         let filter = filteredShops[indexPath.row]
         cell.storeName.text = filter["itemName"]
    }
    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0: 
            //Access itemsA[indexPath.row]
        case 1: 
            //Access itemsB[indexPath.row]
        default: 
           //Access itemsC[indexPath.row]
    }
 return cell
}

func filteredshops(_ searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
    let filteredShopsA = storeLists.filter({ item in
        if let name = item["itemName"], let query = searchController.searchBar.text {
            return name.range(of: query, options: [.caseInsensitive, .diacriticInsensitive]) != nil
        }
        return false
    })
    let filteredShopsB = medicalLists.filter({ item in
        if let name = item["itemName"], let query = searchController.searchBar.text {
            return name.range(of: query, options: [.caseInsensitive, .diacriticInsensitive]) != nil
        }
        return false
    })
    let filteredShopsC = restaurantsLists.filter({ item in
        if let name = item["itemName"], let query = searchController.searchBar.text {
            return name.range(of: query, options: [.caseInsensitive, .diacriticInsensitive]) != nil
        }
        return false
    })
    filteredShops = filteredShopsA + filteredShopsB + filteredShopsC
    print(filteredShops)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

And I have an extension of SearchResultUpdate

```
extension NearByShopVC: UISearchResultsUpdating {
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        filteredshops(searchController.searchBar.text!)
    }
}
```

I had refer this question but not found any solution [How can I filter an array of dictionaries in 'updateSearchResultsForSearchController' to search a UITableView with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37245342/how-can-i-filter-an-array-of-dictionaries-in-updatesearchresultsforsearchcontro)

I tried without the section in the above said question then also not showing proper results. Thank you!!

Comment: I had added a code of filtering which is just for one array i.e. itemA because i don't how to implement for multiple arrays. @NiravD

Comment: There is one way you can display only single section when you filter data

Comment: Can't we search in all section.

Comment: Yes you can search in all section and display result of all section as single section result

Comment: But what to change in code?

Comment: Is it Ok if you having one section when you filter, that filter array having data from all your 3 section? If you want something like that then I will add solution.

Comment: Thats make sense yeah that would be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way for you to is when you filter work with single section, so first change your `filteredshops` like this way.

```
func filteredshops(_ searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
    let filteredShopsA = itemA.filter({ item in
        if let name = item["itemName"], let query = searchController.searchBar.text {
            return name.range(of: query, options: [.caseInsensitive, .diacriticInsensitive]) != nil
        }
        return false
    })
    let filteredShopsB = itemB.filter({ item in
        if let name = item["itemName"], let query = searchController.searchBar.text {
            return name.range(of: query, options: [.caseInsensitive, .diacriticInsensitive]) != nil
        }
        return false
    })
    let filteredShopsC = itemC.filter({ item in
        if let name = item["itemName"], let query = searchController.searchBar.text {
            return name.range(of: query, options: [.caseInsensitive, .diacriticInsensitive]) != nil
        }
        return false
    })
    filteredShops = filteredShopsA + filteredShopsB + filteredShopsC 
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Now with tableView method make change like this way.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if searchController.isActive {
        return 1
    }
    return self.sections.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if searchController.isActive {
        return filteredShops.count
    }   
    switch (section) {
    case 0: 
       return itemsA.count
    case 1: 
       return itemsB.count
    default: 
       return itemsC.count
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "StoreCell") as! UITableViewCell
    if searchController.isActive {
        //Access filteredShops array 
    }  
    else {  
        switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0: 
            //Access itemsA[indexPath.row]
        case 1: 
            //Access itemsB[indexPath.row]
        default: 
            //Access itemsC[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: I implemented with the above solution but its not showing anything, when the search controller is active everything is blank but sections are displayed and when I searched its not giving proper results.

Comment: I did the debugging its showing perfect results but in my tableview not showing perfectly

Comment: Have you tried debugging tableView’s methods ? If possible edit your question with your current tableView's method

Comment: @shahinaliagharia With `cellForRowAt` I have else block also with my solution you need to make else block just like I have and put the switch code inside the else just like I have it