# search bar disappear after press search

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I am using UISearch bar controller 
[image]

after I press on it disappear like this 
[image]

my code :

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // MARK: - Search
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar

}
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
presentViewController(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: Why are you calling "presentViewController(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)" on text did begin editing...?

Comment: @RoyK even If  I do not call it I have the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO
self.definesPresentationContext = NO
```

or use this

```
func willPresentSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)     {
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = true
}

func willDismissSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = false
}
```

for additional Help see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32687240/ios-9-searchbar-disappears-from-table-header-view-when-uisearchcontroller-is-act)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set this property of Viewcontroller

```
self.definesPresentationContext = NO
```